# While reading input block is not exiting

Tags: java

I am trying to take a series of integers from the user and exit the code when user doesn't give any integer and presses enter . I have written this piece of code

```
ArrayList<Integer> series =new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println("Please enter the nos");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
try
{
while(in.hasNextInt())
 {
  String c=in.next();
  series.add(Integer.parseInt(c));
 }
 }
 finally
 {
 in.close();
 }
```

but when i don't enter any number and press enter Console still waits for the input and if then i give any integer it gives exception.

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter, you are not entering anything in, that's why it is still waiting for something. If you put a space and then press enter, it'll count as something. String will accept integers, but will not recognize them as integers. That's why it will give you an error when it computes

```
series.add(Integer.parseInt(c));
```

Why not just use

```
int x = in.nextInt();
```

and set x as the parameter.

Comment: even adding space doesnt help

Comment: have u tried using the int x example instead? After you set x with an int, you can do this..... series.add(Integer.parseInt(x));